# Automatically get points in a given triangular lattice and vice versa？

Tags: computational-geometry, lattices

Given a triangular lattice which grows with number `n`, as follows
[image: triangle-lattices]

I want to list all the connected points in the lattice to form the `pairlist`. As an example:

> n=1: 
> `pairlist={{p_{1},p_{2}},{p_{1},p_{3}},{p_{2},p_{3}}}`
> n=2: 
> `pairlist={{p_{1},p_{2}},{p_{1},p_{4}},{p_{2},p_{3}},{p_{2},p_{4}},{p_{2},p_{5}},{p_{3},p_{5}},{p_{4},p_{5}},{p_{4},p_{6}},{p_{5},p_{6}}}`
> n=3:
> `pairlist={{p_{1},p_{2}},{p_{1},p_{5}},{p_{2},p_{3}},{p_{2},p_{5}},{p_{2},p_{6}},{p_{3},p_{4}},{p_{3},p_{6}},{p_{3},p_{7}},{p_{4},p_{7}},{p_{5},p_{8}},{p_{5},p_{6}},{p_{6},p_{8}},{p_{6},p_{9}},{p_{6},p_{7}},{p_{7},p_{9}},{p_{8},p_{10}},{p_{8},p_{9}},{p_{9},p_{10}}}`

Notice that there is no need to list the elements in `pairlist` in order.

**Questions:**

1. Is there some automatical way to do above tasks?
2. If I have `points= Flatten[Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 1, Binomial[n + 2, 2]}]];`, how can I create the triangle lattice with `points` automatically?

For Question-2, I make one code for `n=2` in the below (is there any simple and general way for different `n`?).

```
pairlists = {};
n = 2;
points = Flatten[Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 1, Binomial[n + 2, 2]}]];

For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[points], ii++,
 For[jj = ii + 1, jj <= Length[points], jj++,
   
   If[(Abs[points[[ii]][[2]]-points[[jj]][[2]]]==1&&ii != 3) ||(Abs[points[[ii]][[2]]-points[[jj]][[2]]]==2&&Abs[ii-jj]==2&& ii!=1 )||(Abs[points[[ii]][[2]]-points[[jj]][[2]]]==3&&Abs[ii-jj]==3&&ii!=3),
      
      AppendTo[pairlists, {points[[ii]], points[[jj]]}];
    ]
   ];
 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 triangleGridGraph[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{vc = Join @@ Table[{j + i/2, i Sqrt[3]/2}, {i, 0, n + 1}, {j, 0,  n - i}]},
    NearestNeighborGraph[vc, VertexCoordinates -> vc, opts]]
```

***Examples:***

```
triangleGridGraph[4, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Index", Center], VertexSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
IndexGraph[triangleGridGraph[4], 
  VertexLabels -> {v_:> Placed[Subscript[P, v], Center]},
  VertexSize->Large]
```

[image]

```
Multicolumn[Panel[
  Labeled[
    triangleGridGraph[#, GraphStyle -> "IndexLabeled", ImageSize -> 300], 
    Style[PromptForm["n", #], 16], Top]] & /@ Range[6], 
  3, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]

To get edges as lists, you `Apply` `List` at level 1 to `EdgeList` of `triangleGridGraph[n]`. For example,

```
List @@@ EdgeList[triangleGridGraph[2]]
```

> ```
> {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 0}}, 
>  {{1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}, {{1, 0}, {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}, 
>  {{2, 0}, {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}, {{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}},  
>  {{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, Sqrt[3]}}, {{3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, Sqrt[3]}}}
> ```

Comment: wonderful, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
basis = {{1, 0}, {Cos[60 Degree], Sin[60 Degree]}};
genpts[n_] :=
 # . basis & /@
  Select[
   Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, n}, {0, n}}], 1],
   Total[#] < n &
  ]

g = With[{pts = genpts[8]}, 
  NearestNeighborGraph[pts, VertexCoordinates -> pts]]
```

[image: triangular lattice]

You can then get pairs of connected vertices as follows:

```
EdgeList[g] /. UndirectedEdge -> List
```

Comment: nice, thank you! What if I don't have the lattice at the begin but I have points with labels `p_{i}`, how can I automatically get the triangular lattice pattern?

Comment: `p_{i}` isn't Mathematica syntax. You can just do `g = NearestNeighborGraph[points, VertexCoordinates -> points]` where points is a list of the coordinates. No need for labels /  symbols here.

Comment: Sorry, `p_{i}` is just `Subscript[p,i]`. I don't know how to write in the stackexchange.

Comment: actually, I need to make labels/symbols. Because later I want to use the symbols for some defined function such as `f[expr,p1,p2]=expr*(1+p1*p2)`, which are not values. @flinty

Comment: I add one example for `n=2` for question 2, could you also have a look? Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't do that with symbols etc. do `points[[1]]`, `points[[2]]` instead of p1,p2.