# Hexa/tria lattice generation

Tags: lattices

How do we generate a regular hexagon / triangle combination of repeating cell geometry shown : (Plastic chair seat weave, Star of David).

Unlike a pure triangle lattice where a node has three intersecting lines this one has alternate sides disappearing when two lines intersect.

Can we modify this recent program? [Recent Tria lattice generation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249454/automatically-get-points-in-a-given-triangular-lattice-and-vice-versa)

[image]

Above base pattern is made in a mechanical software but is cumbersome.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Obligatory question, what have you tried?

Comment: In mechanical modeling before. Only recently I learnt possible in Mma.

Answer (score 3):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/),

```
<< IGraphM`

mesh = IGLatticeMesh["Trihexagonal"]
```

[image]

```
IGMeshGraph[mesh]
```

[image]

See http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#iglatticemesh

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you question correctly, then the pattern consists of lines of 3 types:

1. vertical lines through points x= 0,2,4,..., y=0
2. slanted lines with angle of 30 degrees against the horizontal through points:  x=1,5,9,13,.., y=0
   3)slanted lines with angle of -30 degrees against the horizontal through points:  x=1,5,9,13,.., y=0

We may draw this by:

```
n = 15;
v = 0.5;(*slope*)
linesvert = Table[InfiniteLine[{4 i, 0}, {1, v}], {i, n}];
linesslant1 = Table[InfiniteLine[{4 i, 0}, {-1, v}], {i, n}];
linesslant2 = 
  Table[{InfiniteLine[{1 + 4 i, 0}, {0, 1}], 
    InfiniteLine[{3 + 4 i, 0}, {0, 1}]}, {i, n}];
Graphics[{
  linesvert, linesslant1, linesslant2
  , Red, Thick, Line[{{21, v}, {24, 4 v}, {21, 7 v}, {21, v}}], 
  Line[{{20, 4 v}, {23, 1 v}, {23, 7 v}, {20, 4 v}}]
  }, PlotRange -> {{15, 40}, {0, 8}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
hexagon = {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon @ #, Red, 
     PointSize[Large], Point @ #} & @ CirclePoints[6];

ClearAll[translations, triHex]

translations[w_, h_] := Join @@ Table[{2 j + i, i Sqrt[3]}, {i, 0, h-1}, {j, 0, w-1}]

triHex[w_, h_] := Translate[hexagon, translations[w, h]]

Graphics[triHex[7, 5], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]